# Update a variable in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would need some help with the missing code here:

```
selectInput("portfolio",
            "Portfolio:",
            c("p1","p2"))
## missing code:
## if input$portfolio == "p1" do a bunch of calculations and spit out the variable var (a tibble).

# variable var goes into a reactiveVal...
table <- reactiveVal()
table(var)
```

Comment: do you mean to overwrite base::table() function with reactiveVal here?  Then later you try to use that function `table(var)`.

Answer (score 0):

On the server you can, set `table` (not a great name, perhaps use something else, like `my_table`? to `reactiveValues()`, and then observe for changes in `input$portfolio`

```
table <- reactiveValues(var=NULL)

observeEvent(input$portfolio, {
  if(input$portfolio == "p1") {
    table$var = <- someFunction()
  }
})
```

Here is a full example, using `mtcars`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("make","Make:", choices = rownames(mtcars)),
  tableOutput("subtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  subtable <- reactiveValues(var=NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$make, {
    makes <- rownames(mtcars)
    subtable$var <- dplyr::filter(cbind(makes,mtcars), makes == input$make)
  })
  
  output$subtable <- renderTable(subtable$var)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: In general I just want to access "var" which was created inside observeEvent outside. How can I achieve this?

Comment: the above code actually makes it available to you. Let's say you had a tableOutput UI element called "var", then you could do `output$var<-renderTable(table$var)`

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: Do I need this "fluidPage" and the function if I am using a R notebook instead?

Comment: probably not - I just assumed you were using a shiny app

Comment: I am using flexdashboard